# Fetch a ContextMenu from a handle?

Tags: .net, winforms, contextmenu, handle

Is it possible to fetch a `System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu` instance from a handle?  By fetch I mean building it up from the handle, reading each item, etc.

Attention, this is **not** a `System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip`.

---

Been asked to give more info:
I want to retrieve this menu because I have a natively borderless form on which I draw custom borders and I wish to keep the form's original system menu.

Comment: What sort of handle? HWND or HMENU? In either case, your comment about "building it up from the handle, reading each item, etc." doesn't make much sense -- could you give more description of your inputs and expected outputs?

Comment: What are the odds you are doing this in another process?

Comment: @Hans Passant, they are null. And, @Joe White, I expect to have a context menu with the same structure and properties as the menu of a handle (so HMENU).

Comment: The other process are null.  I don't know how to smoke this, voting to close.

Comment: @Hans Passant, why on earth would you? I intend to take the handle of the system menu of my form and build a context menu out of it, because I have custom form borders and I wish to use that menu.

Comment: Why on Earth are you documenting your question in a comment rather than the question?

Comment: I didn't consider this THAT important.

Comment: Not main menu, System Menu! Click the icon of a window/form or right click it's titlebar. Edit: Removed your comment? xD

Comment: @Vercas yet again your problems are caused by your floating form solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, your edit makes it clear: you have an HMENU of a window's system menu, and you want to show that context menu.

But why on earth do you want to drag the WinForms ContextMenu class into the mix? It's meant for building your own menus and writing .NET code to react to their click events. It's not suited for system menus, which are already populated and already have all the click handling baked in.

If you already have an HMENU for the system menu, then all you need to do is tell the Windows API to show it as a context menu. You would do that by P/Invoking to [TrackPopupMenu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648002%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Aaaaand, from my humble knowledge, keeping those functions isn't possible either. Is it?